# Ionic 2 Zbar plugin bug on iOS11

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, zbar

The main goal of my app is scanning reduction/promotion.

Since the beginning, I used Zbar plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zbar/

I'm on Ionic 2.4 and this plugin works really well, fast etc...

iOS 11 is released and I updated Xcode for working on my iPhone 7.

But since, the scanner doesn't open on my iPhone 7.

When I check on my Xcode Input, that says: 'A scan is already in progress.'

Any ideas?